# Selenium - Click on link

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on a link which is in a list. As can be seen from the screenshot I am trying to click on the "Algeria" link. How can I get there?

[capture of list and elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mauVa.png)

The Css is as follows -  #\33 \2c ALG

xpath is - //*[@id="3,ALG"]

I have tried finding it by xpath and cssSelector but with no luck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`By.linkText()`](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#by-link-text) locator fits here perfectly:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Algeria")).click();
```

You might also need to add an [Explicit Wait](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) to wait for element to be present:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10);

WebElement link = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Algeria"))); 
link.click();
```

---

You may also need to open up the list before clicking the link:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10);

WebElement linkList = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("oList"))); 
linkList.click();

WebElement link = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Algeria"))); 
link.click();
```

Comment: sadly tried that and get the following exception:

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element

Comment: Sadly I get an exception with both. The last answer I get the following exception:

Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"oList"}

Comment: @JamesKing thanks, do you have any (i)frame elements on the page?

Comment: yep

<iframe class="clsGrayborder" id="frmCountry" style="BACKGROUND: #e8e8e8" name="frmCountry" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="pfa_Country.aspx" width="100%"></iframe>

Comment: @JamesKing okay, then, you need to switch to it before making an element search: `driver.switch_to.frame("frmCountry")`. Then, after you are done working inside the iframe, switch back to the default content: `driver.switch_to.default_content()`.

Comment: This may be a stupid question but it cant resolve switch_to.frame or switchTo.frame, is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @JamesKing oops, sorry, too much language switches for today :) Use: `driver.switchTo().frame("frmCountry");` and `driver.switchTo().defaultContent()` accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Yea I jsut found this as you said it. Will give it a go now, Thanks for your help